# innerHtml not marking up correctly (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, innerhtml

I'm using `control.label` to pull text from a database that is dynamically created depending on what part of the application a user is at. I need to make one word ("not") bold and underlined.

In my MSSQL database I wrapped the word not in `<strong>` tags to get it bold first, but Angular is rendering the text literally. It displays the tags instead of bolding it. I've tried DomSanitize and SafeHtml as well, and nothing seems to work.

In my database it's basically `blah blah blah <strong tags>not blah blah blah` under the label column (hence `control.label` when it is called in my HTML component). Then in my HTML I do this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="control.label"></div>
```

Hoping it would properly render the dynamic text, but it does not.

Comment: I don't understand properly your example, `<strong></strong>` as empty tags are there? or something like `Hello <strong>world</strong> how are you?`?

I would suggest that the string actually have a proper HTML format.

You have the option to set it using a `nativeElement` but I would suggest verifying the string is HTML valid, or updating your example properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with DomSanitizer. Bcs innerHTML property sanitizes the content by stripping out HTML tags to prevent XSS.

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class YourComponent {
  safeHtml: SafeHtml;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}


ngOnInit() {
  // this.control is just example
  this.safeHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.control.label);
}
```

}

And now in HTML you can work with your response from DB like this.

```
<div [innerHTML]="safeHtml"></div>
```